# Cauchy's principal part equation

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book *Many-Body Physics* by Coleman, on page 110 there is the following statement:

> Using Cauchy's principal part equation, $1/(x-i \delta) = P(1/x) + i \pi \delta(x)$, where $P$ is the principal part.

Here $\delta$ is a number and $\delta(x)$ I presume to be the Dirac delta.
I am not sure what this means. I assume it is related to the principal part of a function but, otherwise, I don't know how to obtain this. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the $\delta$ supposed to be a Dirac delta on both sides?

Comment: No, the delta on the LHS is a small variable and on the RHS the delta is an Dirac delta function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what’s called the Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem; you can check [Wikipedia's article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) about it.

Comment: Thanks. The only issue I have is that here it is used without the integration. How do we know that if the integral is the same the integrands will be too?

Comment: Note that the author, as well as Srednicki in *Quantum Field Theory*, calls "principal part" to what often in literature---including Wikipedia---is called *Cauchy principal value*. Shokhotski-Plemelj theorem specifically implies the expression cited by the OP, which indeed shows no integral.